# Exchange server not leaving a copy on my mail server

Tags: exchange, email

Our company has a main mail server. An exchange sits in our office which pulls mails from mail server. we use outlook to connect to our office exchange server and send/receive emails.

Now, the problem is, the exchange server is not leaving a copy on our main mail server. It is just pulling all mails in the mail server and storing locally.

Is there any way to set at exchange/mailbox level to restrict the exchange server to leave a copy of message on the main mail server?

Comment: This setup seems like an incredible waste of resources.  Why is it set up this way?

Comment: Yeah that's true.Even, I got confused with this setup when I look at it for the first time few days back. Is there a way to resolve the issue??

Comment: Can you be more specific about the protocol being used to communicate, I like others have had to assume based on the limited detail in your question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using a POP3 connector. In my opinion, the behavior you are seeing is perfectly normal. I use a similar setup here for my Exchange 2007 configuration. Its not SBS, so I use a 3rd party connector to connect to the POP3 mailboxes. The mail is downloaded to the Exchange mailbox, and removed from the POP3 mailbox. Its nice to know that if our internal system goes down, we can still do business via POP3 if necessary, and the mail is still being delivered.

My question is, do you need mail to stay on the first server? If so, you will need to adjust the settings of the connector to leave mail on the server after download.

Comment: Hi Dan!! Thanks for you reply. Yes, I need to stay email on my first server.

Comment: What is the OS on the Exchange server? Is it SBS?

Answer (score 0):

If you had the mail server forward mail to the exchange server rather then the exchange server fetch the mail. Then a copy would always be on the server. That's a work around if exchange server doesn't allow leaving a copy on the mail server.

Comment: I am afraid, the exchange server is pulling mails from mail server. Not sure which option to set on the exchange server to keep a copy on the mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use this before for a client running SBS 2003.  The company mail was hosted (POP3) but they wanted other features of Exchange.  In my case I used [**Microsoft's Exchange Connector for POP3 Mailboxes**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc747541(WS.10).aspx).  It was, um, somewhat evil.

There are quite a few tools to use to get Exchange to retrieve (pull) mail from an external source (I'm assuming POP3 in your case) and deliver to internal mailboxes.  Which one are you using?  You'll need to configure the tool you're using in Exchange to leave the mail on the remote server.  Keep in mind that it's possible the tool you're using doesn't support that option.

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a long shot, but I've seen this happen at an individual mailbox level, where Outlook has been incorrectly configured to deliver emails to a PST file instead of an OST file.

Double-check the mailbox options in Outlook under the Data Files tab and see what's set up there. If there is a PST file configured as the default delivery location, you'll need to set up an OST file, then use the File > Import/Export tool to restore the data back to the mailbox.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with client application behavior.

Comment: Whoops.... Misread the question :(